# `UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x8b in position 1: invalid start byte`

Tags: python, session, unicode, response

Unable to decode response object

```
 text = response.read()
 if isinstance(text, bytes):  
    text = text.decode('utf-8')
```

`text` has this data in it,  b'\x1f\x8b\x08\x00\x00'

Comment: are you sure that response is not in gzip?

Comment: Have you tried `latin-1` instead of `utf-8`?

Comment: what module do you use ? What url did you use ? What headers did you use ? Maybe you really get compressed response and you have to decompress it or use different headers. Better show minimal working code with URL so we could run it and see problem.

Comment: @OlvinRoght I did print(response.info().get('Content-Encoding')) and it returned gzip. I will check on how to handle this response type.

Comment: latin-1 didnot work

Comment: @furas Yea looks like I'm getting a compressed response

Comment: if you send header `Accept-Encoding` then use only `deflate` and don't use `gzip,br`. If you download zip file then save it in file using bytes mode - `open(..., 'wb')` and open it with any external program for archives. Or you can try to use python module `zipfile`, `gzip`, `tarfile` if you know what type of archive you downloaded.

Comment: @furas The only header that i send is "Content-Type":" application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=utf-8". I will try to add Accept-Encoding

Comment: you can add `Accept-Encoding: deflate` to inform server that it has to send back uncompressed data. I checked [Gzip in wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gzip) and it sends `1f 8b` as two first bytes (so caller "magic number") so you have data in gzip format. If `Accept-Encoding: deflate` will not help then you will have to use module `gzip` to manually decompress it. Or you could use module `requests` which should automatically decompress response.

Comment: import gzip
data = gzip.decompress(text).decode('utf-8') //solved, thanks everyone

Answer (score 11):

`0x1f 0x8b` is [the starting bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gzip#File_format) for gzip files. [`.decode`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#bytes.decode) defaults to `utf-8` which does not expect that start byte sequence - hence the `invalid start byte` message.

Try using the [gzip](https://docs.python.org/3/library/gzip.html) module to decompress the file and then attempt to decode it (provided that the results are actually decodable). Example from the documentation, adapted for your case:

```py
import gzip
data = gzip.decompress(response.read())
text = data.decode('utf-8')
```

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem and I just did not notice that **my file was actually compressed**.
Even if the extension is not there, your file may be compressed.